# How to select a Nullable decimal type in LINQ?

Tags: c#

I have a column of type `decimal` in Db which is nullable too. What I want that if it's null then display `0.0`. For that I am trying following in my LINQ Statement:

```
CostPerUnit = od.CostPerUnit == null ? "0.0": od.CostPerUnit
```

Which gives error:

```
Error   9   Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'decimal'
```

Complete Statement also given for ref:

```
var rmas = (
                    from o in db.Orders
                    join od in db.OrderDetails on o.OrderNumber equals od.OrderNumber
                    join r in db.RMAs on o.OrderNumber equals r.OrderNumber
                    join rd in db.RMADetails on r.RMANumber equals rd.RMANumber
                    where (rd.WrongSKU == od.SKU)
                    join i in db.Inventory on od.SKU equals i.LocalSKU into grp
                    from g in grp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new
                    {
                        r.RMANumber
                                    ,
                        r.Reason
                                    ,
                        o.Name
                                    ,
                        o.Company
                                    ,
                        o.Address
                                    ,
                        o.Address2
                                    ,
                        o.City,
                        o.State
                                    ,
                        o.Country
                                    ,
                        o.Email
                                    ,
                        o.Zip
                                    ,
                        o.Phone
                                    ,
                        o.ShipName,
                        o.ShipCompany
                                    ,
                        o.ShipAddress
                                    ,
                        o.ShipAddress2
                                    ,
                        o.ShipCity
                                    ,
                        o.ShipCountry
                                    ,
                        o.ShipState
                                    ,
                        o.ShipPhone
                                    ,
                        o.ShipZip

                                    ,
                        o.OrderNumber
                                    ,
                        o.ShippingTotal
                                    ,
                        o.BalanceDue
                                    ,
                        r.Status
                                    ,
                        OrderDate = o.OrderDate
                                    ,
                        DateIssued = r.DateIssued
                                    ,
                        SerialNumbers = rd.SerialNumbers ?? ""
                                    ,
                        o.SourceOrderID
                                    ,
                        od.SKU
                                    ,
                        od.ItemNumber
                                    ,
                        QTYOrdered = od.QuantityOrdered
                                    ,
                        od.QuantityReturned
                                    ,
                        rd.QuantityAuthorized
                                    ,
                        RMA_ItemNumber1 = rd.ItemNumber
                                    ,
                        rd.Price
                                    ,
                        rd.WrongSKU
                                    ,
                        g.Text1
                                    ,

                        CostPerUnit = od.CostPerUnit == null ? "0.0": od.CostPerUnit

                    }
                ).Take(50).ToList();
```

Comment: 1) Use the decimal literal `0m` or `0.0m` instead of the string `"0.0"` 2) You can use the null coalescence operator `??` instead of the conditional operator `? :`. Combining these changes, you could write `od.CostPerUnit ?? 0.0m`.

Comment: When you say you want to "display" `0.0`, why not just handle that in the UI rather than a complex operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What you should do is this**

```
CostPerUnit = od.CostPerUnit ?? 0.0m
```

This uses the Null Coalescing operator.  It's specifically for adding default values for nullable types

**What you can do is this**

```
CostPerUnit = od.CostPerUnit == null ? 0.0m : od.CostPerUnit.Value
```

note the `.Value` property.  It get's the non-nullable version of the decimal.

---

**what you might be intending to do is this**

```
CostPerUnit = od.CostPerUnit == null ? "0.0": od.CostPerUnit.Value.ToString()
```

That will make `CostPerUnit` a string

Comment: I don't see the point of the `m` suffix, there's no difference between `0.0m`, `0m` and plain old `0`.

Comment: @DavidG 1) I think it's clearer to use a decimal literal instead of using the implicit conversion from an integer to a decimal. 2) decimal remembers how many trailing zeros you specified. So `0.0m` and `0m` will look different once you convert them to string.

Comment: @DavidG 0 works.  0.0 will give you an error because the compiler assums it to be a double and not a decimal.  I like using the `m` notation, because it makes it more clear that to readers of the code that you're working with decimals.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes but whatever is used it still won't "display" as `0.0` for the user. This is a UI problem.

Comment: @DavidG `0.0m` displays as `"0.0"` to the user (with localized decimal separator), `0m` displays as `"0"` to the user. But you might be right that doing the defaulting closer to the UI might be better, but without context I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @DavidG the user never has to see the `m`